# How to implement captcha in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, captcha

I've found two plugins in CakePHP using recaptcha, but they are outdated. How can I use captcha in CakePHP? I don't believe I have to write my own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple math captcha solution:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/08/09/how-to-implement-captchas-properly/

Many handicapped persons favor such an approach since they cannot read those image captchas.
and even normal people like you and me often fail hard on those image things.

The 2.0 files are in https://github.com/dereuromark/tools

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](http://gablog.eu/void/2010/09/08/captcha-for-cakephp-1-3-with-kcaptcha/) :

It is going to use KCAPTCHA to generate Captchas and verify them in form submissions in CakePHP

Comment: CakePHP 2.0 version is needed.

Comment: CKAPTCHA is an independent vendor. It works perfectly fine with any version of Cake. I've recently migrated from 1.3 to 2.0 and the Captcha was working perfectly without any change. Of course if you use a plugin or component to properly encapsulate this feature, the file naming convention was altered slightly for the good, but that definitely does not qualify this for a downvote. KCAPTCHA is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You could take one of those plugins and migrate it to CakePHP 2.0 by following the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use easy-to-use CakePHP Captcha Component https://github.com/arvindk/Cakephp-Captcha-Component-2.0. It works with CakePHP 2.x version upto 2.4.1. Model name and Field name are configurable. Supports automatic Model Validation for captcha (for both image and math captcha).

Here's how to show math captcha instead of image captcha, which is shown by default.

```
$this->Captcha = $this->Components->load('Captcha', 
array('captchaType'=>'math', //or 'image' (requires GD library)
'jquerylib'=>true, 
'modelName'=>'Signup', 
'fieldName'=>'captcha'));
```

Comment: It includes a simple math question now. For example,

    $this->Captcha = $this->Components->load('Captcha', array('captchaType'=>'math', 'jquerylib'=>true, 'modelName'=>'Signup', 'fieldName'=>'captcha')); //load it